# Conditioned does not give an answer

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Why does Mathematica simply return this code without an answer;

```
Expectation[1 - (2 Kt)/(Ka + Kb) \[Conditioned] Ka < Kb, {Ka \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[4 Kt, 4 - 4 Kt], Kb \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[4 Kt, 4 - 4 Kt]}]
```

Comment: That is because *Mathematica* just doesn't recognize that expectation.  However, in this case I believe the condition `Ka < Kb` is superfluous.  All that condition does is randomly toss roughly half of the unconditioned samples. 
 So removing that condition will get you the same answer (and an actual answer).

Comment: `1 - 2 Kt/Expectation[(Ka + Kb), {Ka \[Distributed] 
      BetaDistribution[4 Kt, 4 - 4 Kt], 
     Kb \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[4 Kt, 4 - 4 Kt]}]` you can get the expectation of Ka +Kb  instead of the whole expression

Comment: JimB, how do you conclude the condition simply wastes about half the sample? Is that because the expression before the condition already accounts for ka < kb?

Answer (score 2):

The brute force approach is to write the associated integrals directly (by noting that the joint density of `Ka` and `Kb` given `Ka < Kb` is just twice the product of the two marginal densities.  Here is the estimate of the mean of `1-Kt/(Ka+Kb)` with `Kt=1/2`:

```
NIntegrate[(1 - Kt/(Ka + Kb)) 2 ((1 - Ka)^(3 - 4 Kt) Ka^(-1 + 4 Kt))/
   Beta[4 Kt, 4 - 4 Kt] ((1 - Kb)^(3 - 4 Kt) Kb^(-1 + 4 Kt))/
   Beta[4 Kt, 4 - 4 Kt] /. Kt -> 1/2, {Ka, 0, 1}, {Kb, 0, Ka}]
(* 0.427106 *)
```

It appears that the integral only exists when $1/8 < Kt < 1$.

To justify that the conditioning is unnecessary in this case one can do a bit of handwaving:  Because the pivotal statistic is the sum `Ka + Kb`, `Ka` and `Kb` are independent with the same marginal distribution, and we condition on `Ka < Kb`, such a set of samples from that conditional distribution will be indistinguishable from those conditioned on `Ka > Kb`.  Together those two comprise the complete set of potential samples.  Therefore, conditioning on `Ka < Kb` is unnecessary.  (If the marginal distributions of `Ka` and `Kb` were different, this would not be the case.)

Additionally, one can check the expected value for various values of `Kt` and see that the results are identical for the conditioned and unconditioned approaches.

```
NIntegrate[(1 - Kt/(Ka + Kb)) ((1 - Ka)^(3 - 4 Kt) Ka^(-1 + 4 Kt))/
   Beta[4 Kt, 4 - 4 Kt] ((1 - Kb)^(3 - 4 Kt) Kb^(-1 + 4 Kt))/
   Beta[4 Kt, 4 - 4 Kt] /. Kt -> 1/2, {Ka, 0, 1}, {Kb, 0, 1}]
(* 0.427106 *)
```